# Вывод и проверка скриптом JS дважды четного числа

Tags: javascript

в условии число называется «дважды четным», если и оно само, и сумма его цифр - четные. Напишите скрипт, который принимает с клавиатуры трехзначное положительное число и проверяет, является ли оно «дважды четным». В соответствии с результатом проверки надо вывести на экран соответствующее текстовое сообщение. Вот код который получилось составить, но не получается сделать вывод чисел.

```
    function primer() {
let a;
let summa=0;
let x = document.getElementById('d1').value;
if (x == '') {
alert ('Вы ничего не ввели')
}
else {
if ( x > 99 && x < 1000) is {
if (x % 2 == 0) {
alert ('ваше число чётное') 
} 
else {
alert ('вы ввели нечетное')
} 
} 
else {
alert ('ваше число не трехзначное') 
} 
} 
for (summa=summa++a)
document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML="вес числа" +sum;
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Скрипт JS на проверку четности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1219972/%d0%a1%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bf%d1%82-js-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8)

Answer (score 1):

сумма цифр числа - это:

```
let value = 1234
let count = 0

while (value > 0) {
    count += value % 10
    value = parseInt(value / 10)
}
```

а чтобы проверить на чётность надо просто посмотреть остаток от деления на 2:

```
let is_even = value % 2 == 0
```